# How do you get the created object of a findOneAndUpdate with {upsert: true} in MongooseJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

What I am doing:

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: id_from_api},
    {$set: bookObj},
    {upsert: true},
    function (err, book) {
        handleError(err);
        console.log(book);
    }
);
```

I am expecting book to be a book document but it is only a document when it exists, not when it is created as a result of the upsert being true.

My Question is this: How do i get the newly created book document?

**Update**
Simply had to explicitly set the option `new` to `true`

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: id_from_api},
    {$set: bookObj},
    {upsert: true, new: true},
    function (err, book) {
        handleError(err);
        console.log(book);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs for [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) there is an option called `new` that used to be defaulted to true

```
new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the original.
defaults to false (changed in 4.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate the book object beforehand, like this:

```
var book = new Book(bookObj);

Book.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: book._id},
    {$set: book.toObject()},
    {upsert: true},
    function (err, result) {
        handleError(err);
        console.log(result ? "Updated existing object:" : "New object created:");
        console.log(result || book);
    }
);
```